# 3rd party verification of separately encrypted files

Tags: encryption, pgp

I'm trying to figure out how to verify whether a file's contents are unchanged even though it has been re-encrypted and the 3rd party cannot know what is inside of the file.  A contrived example to illustrate:

1. John sends sha1sum to Bill with the name "cats_jumping_on_balls.wmv" but never sends the actual file.  Then he goes into the mountains, never to be heard from again.
2. Sally thinks she has the same file but re-encrypted and wants to check.  She sends the entire **re-encrypted** file to Bill in order to make sure.
3. Bill checks the file somehow and says Sally actually **does** have the same file, and replies as such by providing a detached signature to Sally that will allow others to trust her and her re-encrypted file.

My thoughts are that the only way to do this would be for Bill to decrypt the file sent by Sally and use sha1sum to verify.  My issues with this is that Bill now has access to the video.

What I could find on the internet about something related to this are:

1. Zero knowledge proofs, which I know little to nothing about.
2. Double encryption.  So that Bill only sees the inner 'shell' of the whole encrypted file but can still check to see that they are the same.  This assumes John provided the sha1sum for the inner encrypted shell.

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why not have Sally just decrypt the file back to the initial state, have her generate the hash and have it sent to to you. You the compare hashes. This is assuming she doesnt already know bills hash.

Comment: Two reasons, 1. She's not allowed to know John's hash and 2. She intends to use a verifying detached signature that Bill can provide her with to prove that she has the file to a fourth person.

Comment: in that case you might want to add those additional stipulations to your original question so anyone else is not read the comments in order to find that out.

Comment: I have modified the question to include those additional stipulations.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If John only provides a hash of the original file and Sally provides only the encrypted file without encryption key then Bill cannot verify that the origin for both transformations was the same. Given that you explain the knowledge and capabilities of the peers only with this example one can only say that this is impossible in this case. If you would more formally describe what each party knows, can, is allowed to do and is allowed to know (some of this is already in your comment) then one might maybe provide a solution.